# Sunspot search result is empty when using rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sunspot

The search function works fine in development and Production. But when I run Rspec tests. the result array is always empty

In my search action log, I can see the data has been indexed and fetched correctly:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "ga_client_id"=>"", "search"=>"David"}
SOLR Request (3.9ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x007fb7f9141f00> parameters={data:       fq=type%3AToon&sort=created_at_d+asc&q=David&fl=%2A+score&qf=name_text+author_text+toon_typetext+tags_text&defType=dismax&start=0&rows=9, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}, path: select, uri: http://localhost:8981/solr/select?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: , retry_503: , retry_after_limit: } ]
Toon Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "toons".* FROM "toons" WHERE "toons"."id" IN (15550, 15551, 15552) AND (state in ('created','flagged'))
```

In my Controller

```
  @search = Toon.solr_search do
    fulltext params[:search]
    order_by :created_at, :asc
    paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 9
  end
  @toons = @search.results
```

My rspec test: https://gist.github.com/jianbo/6360486

In testing View

```
  <%= @search.inspect %> This output correctly as follow:
  <Sunspot::Search:{:fq=>["type:Toon"], :sort=>"created_at_d asc", :q=>"papabear", :fl=>"* score", :qf=>"name_text author_text toon_type_text tags_text", :defType=>"dismax", :start=>0, :rows=>9}>

  <%= @toons.inspect %> is empty array
```

UPDATE
I just found that if I do no clear the index and the database, and after running the test twice, I was able to search for the result that was in the first run test.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same problem.

Comment: Have you setup sunspot.yml for your test env? test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test

Answer (score -1):

You will want to fire up a Solr instance for the tests. There is a very helpful snippet here that can help: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/RSpec-and-Sunspot#running-sunspot-during-testing

Comment: Comment from the page you're linking:


"Unit tests should not touch Solr. If you want to test Solr do so in integration tests with something like Steak or Cucumber."